# Color of a button changes without a reason

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have two views. After clicking on the button in the first view, a popup window appears (second view). In it, if a user does some action, the popup disappears, and the user is once again in the first view and the button is of a different color (which is great!). However, when I touch down on it and move the finger away (so I won't click it) it changes back to its initial color. The same happens when an alert appears in the window - the button changes back to its initial color. Any help?

I changed the color of the button through delegate and line:

```
cell.btn2.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
```

Comment: Any reason you’re not using .setTitleColor?

Comment: cell.btn2.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
was the answer, thx

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.btn2.tintColor = UIColor.gray` to change the tint color, rather than directly affecting the titleLabel's textColor.